# Property not appearing when serializing dataclass to dict

Tags: python, serialization, data-class

My code:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    b = 5

print(asdict(A()) # prints "{}"
```

How can I make it print the `b` as member of the dict?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a type annotation on `b`:

`b: int = 5`